# reference to lxml node

Tags: python, lxml

i'm iterating xml node values, which i get from xpath query. And i need to assign a reference to some node value.

Here what i want to to:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(some_xml)
nodes = doc.xpath('some_query')
for node in nodes:
    if node.text == 'smth':
        #there i need to assign reference
        reference = node.text

#after iterating i need to that change the node value
reference = 'hello world'
```

is there a way to do it in python?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store a reference to the actual node instead:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(some_xml)
nodes = doc.xpath('some_query')
for node in nodes:
    if node.text == 'smth':
        reference = node

reference.text = 'hello world'
```

Comment: that raised AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: Then you didn't store a reference to the node, but to `None`. Or maybe you had `None` in first place. In any instance, paste your real code so we can find out what's wrong